# Sinch Calls App-App doesn't work. reason: UserNotFound

Tags: android, sdk, sinch

I'm developing an App with Calls using Sinch.
My Users Ids are numbers. 
I am trying to call through my App to user with the Id 7 but this is the response that I got from Sinch SDK:

> sinch-android-rtc﹕ Error(code: 4000, domain: api, message:
>   UserNotFound (2228275), data: {serverCode: 2228275, serverMessage:
>   UserNotFound})

Can Anybody help me?

Thank You

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

That means you have not yet started a Sinch client with user 7. you need to at least start it once then you can either send push to notify about incoming calls or use active connection

Also 7 is to short, should be at least 3 in length

Answer (score 1):

If you get "User Not Found" message when you try to make a call, it means no SinchClient was started using the recipient Id. Try to compare your code with the completed source code available at github.com/sinch/app-app-calling-android or you can post your code

Try to use your name as an Id like "carlos"

Answer (score 0):

If you get "User Not Found" message when you try to make a call, it means no SinchClient was started using the recipient Id.
and just check the name of the user by which you are making the connection it must be unique and it must not contain any spaces.